# Not able to use Google Place API

Tags: java, android, intellij-idea, google-places-api

I am trying to create small app which simply connects to Google Place API and expected output is to get current location in Json data.

But before that, I am facing this error. Please help. I have tried lots of things and none of them seems to be working. If anyone knows the best way to learn this (with current Google Place APIs), Please suggest me as I am tired of doing configuration for two weeks and not writing single line of code instead.

Here is the code for the same. (I am using the [Getting Started](https://developers.google.com/places/android-api/start) code from Google Developers guides.) It should return the likely places but it only logs the error.

**MainActivity.java**

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class MyActivity extends Activity {
      @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        GooglePlaceCommunicator communicator=new GooglePlaceCommunicator();
        communicator.GetData();
        TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtView);
        tv.setText("Connection Done");

    }
}
```

**AndroidManifext.xml** (I have removed API key from below file just to post it here.)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          package="com.example.GoogleAPIsLearning"
          android:versionCode="1"
          android:versionName="1.0">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="16"/>
    <application android:label="@string/app_name" android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher">
        <activity android:name="MyActivity"
                  android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <meta-data
                android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
                android:value="APIKey"
                />
    </application>
</manifest>
```

GooglePlaceCommunicator.java

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.multidex.MultiDex;
import android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication;
import android.util.Log;
import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.PendingResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.ResultCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.location.places.PlaceLikelihood;
import com.google.android.gms.location.places.PlaceLikelihoodBuffer;
import com.google.android.gms.location.places.Places;


public class GooglePlaceCommunicator extends MultiDexApplication implements GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {

        private GoogleApiClient mGoogleAPIClient;
        public  void GetData(){
            try {
                Log.i("Inside Try","Before GooglePlaceCommunicator");
                mGoogleAPIClient = new GoogleApiClient
                        .Builder(this)
                        .addApi(Places.GEO_DATA_API)
                        .addApi(Places.PLACE_DETECTION_API)
                        .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                        .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                        .build();

                Log.i("Inside Try","After GooglePlaceCommunicator");

                PendingResult<PlaceLikelihoodBuffer> result = Places.PlaceDetectionApi.getCurrentPlace(mGoogleAPIClient, null);

                result.setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<PlaceLikelihoodBuffer>() {
                                             @Override
                                             public void onResult(PlaceLikelihoodBuffer placeLikelihoods) {
                                                 for (PlaceLikelihood placeLikelihood : placeLikelihoods) {
                                                     Log.i("TAG", String.format("Place %s has likelihood : %g",
                                                             placeLikelihood.getPlace().getName(), placeLikelihood.getLikelihood()));

                                                 }
                                                 placeLikelihoods.release();

                                             }
                                         }
                );
            } catch (Exception e) {
                        Log.i("ERRTBP: ",e.toString());
                }

        }

        @Override
        public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
                //super.onStart();
                mGoogleAPIClient.connect();
        }

        @Override
        public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {
                mGoogleAPIClient.disconnect();
               // super.onStop();

        }

        @Override
        public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

        }

        @Override
        protected  void attachBaseContext(Context Base) {
                super.attachBaseContext(Base);
                MultiDex.install(this);
        }
}
```

As you can see in above class, I have changed AttachBaseContext method as well because I am running this application directly on my android device (4.1.2 - API16)

Log contains something as below. and that is the error I am not able to solve despite wasting last 2 weeks trying different approaches.
As you can see it goes inside Communicator class and logs data but at the end it just logs null pointer exception.

```
10-08 14:19:02.840  11979-11979/com.example.GoogleAPIsLearning I/Inside Try﹕ Before GooglePlaceCommunicator
10-08 14:19:02.850  11979-11979/com.example.GoogleAPIsLearning I/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find method android.app.Notification$Builder.setLocalOnly, referenced from method com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil.zza
10-08 14:19:02.850  11979-11979/com.example.GoogleAPIsLearning W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 229: Landroid/app/Notification$Builder;.setLocalOnly (Z)Landroid/app/Notification$Builder;
10-08 14:19:02.850  11979-11979/com.example.GoogleAPIsLearning D/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x00c8
10-08 14:19:02.850  11979-11979/com.example.GoogleAPIsLearning I/dalvikvm﹕ DexOpt: access denied from Lcom/google/android/gms/common/GooglePlayServicesUtil; to field Landroid/app/Notification;.extras
10-08 14:19:02.850  11979-11979/com.example.GoogleAPIsLearning W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve instance field 17
10-08 14:19:02.850  11979-11979/com.example.GoogleAPIsLearning D/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: replacing opcode 0x54 at 0x00e7
10-08 14:19:02.854  11979-11979/com.example.GoogleAPIsLearning I/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find method android.os.UserManager.getApplicationRestrictions, referenced from method com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil.zzah
10-08 14:19:02.854  11979-11979/com.example.GoogleAPIsLearning W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 1384: Landroid/os/UserManager;.getApplicationRestrictions (Ljava/lang/String;)Landroid/os/Bundle;
10-08 14:19:02.854  11979-11979/com.example.GoogleAPIsLearning D/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0012
10-08 14:19:02.855  11979-11979/com.example.GoogleAPIsLearning E/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find class 'android.app.AppOpsManager', referenced from method com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil.zzb
10-08 14:19:02.855  11979-11979/com.example.GoogleAPIsLearning W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve check-cast 25 (Landroid/app/AppOpsManager;) in Lcom/google/android/gms/common/GooglePlayServicesUtil;
10-08 14:19:02.855  11979-11979/com.example.GoogleAPIsLearning D/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: replacing opcode 0x1f at 0x000e
10-08 14:19:02.856  11979-11979/com.example.GoogleAPIsLearning I/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find method android.content.pm.PackageManager.getPackageInstaller, referenced from method com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil.zzj
10-08 14:19:02.856  11979-11979/com.example.GoogleAPIsLearning W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 483: Landroid/content/pm/PackageManager;.getPackageInstaller ()Landroid/content/pm/PackageInstaller;
10-08 14:19:02.856  11979-11979/com.example.GoogleAPIsLearning D/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x000b
10-08 14:19:02.857  11979-11979/com.example.GoogleAPIsLearning I/ERRTBP:﹕ java.lang.NullPointerException
10-08 14:19:02.900  11979-11979/com.example.GoogleAPIsLearning D/libEGL﹕ loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libEGL_mtk.so
10-08 14:19:02.907  11979-11979/com.example.GoogleAPIsLearning D/libEGL﹕ loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_mtk.so
10-08 14:19:02.912  11979-11979/com.example.GoogleAPIsLearning D/libEGL﹕ loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libGLESv2_mtk.so
10-08 14:19:02.937  11979-11979/com.example.GoogleAPIsLearning D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Enabling debug mode 0
```

Also, below mentioned error is something where I have spent most of the time looking for the solution.

`Could not find class 'android.app.AppOpsManager', referenced from method com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil.zzb`

Google Play Services version is as below.

[image]

Comment: are you using older google play services library?

Comment: @KaranMer, I have just edited the question. It is not older one.

Answer (score 0):

Add this line to your manifest file

```
<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" 
android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version"/>
```

Comment: I added this line but error still persists : **Could not find class 'android.app.AppOpsManager', referenced from method com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil.zzb**